# Parallel executions of stored procedure using Nested table

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, nested-table

I am using nested tables in stored procedure and FORALL statements to speed up the procedure execution which is taking close to 30min for a run, When I execute the procedure from single system then execution is fast and I was able to get required output.

Problem is when the same procedure is executed in parallel from multiple systems at same time, results are wrong. Assuming the behaviour being data inserted in same nested table at same time, but I am not sure how to achieve correct results or how to manipulate the nested table behaviour.

Created a object first:

```
create or replace TYPE JR_Type AS OBJECT

(
"JOB_ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "E_ID" NCHAR(64), 
    "USER_NAME" NCHAR(32), 
    "START_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "END_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 

);
```

Create a nested table on this object.

```
create or replace TYPE JR_Table AS TABLE OF JR_Type ;
```

Now below way I used in procedure:

My procedure is huge but in a simpler way I am using in below way.

```
create or replace Procedure data_test (E in nchar, J in number)
      AS

      Exec_data JR_Table;   //Created a nested table variable
      
      BEGIN
      
    select JR_Type (job_id, e_id,  USER_NAME, start_time, end_time)
                    bulk collect into Exec_data   //Bulk collect into this variable
                    from ( taBLE);
                    
                    
                     FORALL counter in Exec_data.first..Exec_data.last    //insert using FORALL
                insert into DATA_TEMP1 Values
                (Exec_data(counter).JOB_ID, Exec_data(counter).E_ID, Exec_data(counter).START_TIME, Exec_data(counter).END_TIME;
    
                commit;
                
                End;
```

I am sure their should be a way to handle this but unfortunately it is out of my understanding, Hope I will get some help.

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------

2 executions insert data in same table, FYI input data is different in 2 executions.

```
total records should be 120

1st execution 74

2nd execution 56
```

With this design records varies according to execution once I will get 80 or 90 0r 60.

Comment: when you say the results are wrong, what do you mean ? you are running in parallel the same procedure , I guess with different input parameters, but I don't see any relationship between the input parameters and the nested table

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes input parameters are different relationship here is depending on input parameters query will fetch data and store in nested table, in this case data from two input parameters is being clubbed or overwritten and results are not as expected. I assume when procedure is executed in parallel data from 2nd system is replacing the data that is already inserted by the exection from 1st system and end result would be a wrong data, I need a way that in parallel execution data should be stored saperately and should be displayed and not overwritten.

Comment: then you need ISOLATION LEVEL in your transaction.

Comment: ok this is a new concept now, can you please explain how does this work in this case?

Comment: I put you an answer with an explanation. I think it might solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

As you are commenting problems with concurrent access, a way to solve this is applying a different ISOLATION_LEVEL, in this case SERIALIZABLE. If you don't specify an isolation level, the default will be READ COMMITED, which means that each query can see only data committed before the query, not the transaction, began. However, **it does not prevent other transaction from modifying data read by a query**.  Thus, it is possible that other transactions can change data between executions of the query.  Any transaction that executes a given query more than once can experience non-repeatable reads or phantoms.

With the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level, only data that was committed at the start of the transaction plus those made by the transaction itself through INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs can be accessed by a query, so **the query won't see any other data commited by other processes.**

```
create or replace Procedure data_test (E in nchar, J in number)
AS

      Exec_data JR_Table;   //Created a nested table variable
      
      BEGIN
          -- set isolation level ( only the data manipulated here will be available to this process
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '  ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ' ; -- session level 
  SET TRANSACTION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- transaction level
    select JR_Type (job_id, e_id,  USER_NAME, start_time, end_time)
                    bulk collect into Exec_data   //Bulk collect into this variable
                    from ( taBLE);
                    
                    
                     FORALL counter in Exec_data.first..Exec_data.last    //insert using FORALL
                insert into DATA_TEMP1 Values
                (Exec_data(counter).JOB_ID, Exec_data(counter).E_ID, Exec_data(counter).START_TIME, Exec_data(counter).END_TIME;
    
                commit;
                
                End;
```

You can use

ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION LEVEL xxx -- affects session behaviour

SET TRANSACTION LEVEL xxx -- affects the transaction itself

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, My day is done today will test and accept it tomorrow

Comment: One question will this change effect the procedure execution time?

Comment: I don't think so , but be careful when you applied the isolation. I put you two way, one affect the whole session from that moment, the other the transaction. I would test it first with SET TRANSACTION LEVEL in your procedure

Comment: I tried your solution, By using `set transaction level` result didn't change, by using at `session level` both the session went into dead lock state, procedures supposed to execute in 30 sec didn't exit after a minute. Is their any other way I can accomplish this or is this even possible?

Comment: can you put in the question the results of two processes running at the same time ? what output do you get in both ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, struck in other priority work, please check my edit.